# Add image to screen from computer

Tags: android

How do I add an image from my computer to a screen on the app? Do I have to copy the image from my pc to the android app program somewhere? And then reference it?
I got this far:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="236dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo" />
```

But its not what I want. I'm guessing my photo reference needs to go at  `android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo"` but how?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your image into res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-xdpi, res/drawable-ldpi of your android application project.
You can even directly drag and drop from File Explorer into eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Drag your desired photo into one of the drawable folders:

[image]

2 - In your ImageView xml, Where it says "abc_ab_bottom_solid_light_holo", replace that with  the name of the photo you just dropped into one of the drawable folders. It should now work.